# React conditionally set navigation

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm populating a table by mapping each row, and inside mapping each column . I want to enable a `NavLink` instance only if its the first column of each row . I also want to use the row `ID` and concat it to the path . 
Right now I have this:

```
       {props.tableData
        .map(n => {
          return (
            <TableRow key={n.id}>
              <TableCell component="th" padding="checkbox">
                <Switch
                  checked={n.commission === 1}
                  onChange={(event) => props.setPayment(n.id, event.target.checked)}
                  color="primary"
                />
              </TableCell>
              {
                Columns.map((c,index) => {
                  return (
                    index === 1 && <NavLink className={classes.navLink} activeClassName={classes.activeNavLink}  to "/brokers/".concat(n.id) >
                    <TableCell key={c.key} component="th" padding="checkbox">{c.format(n[c.key])}</TableCell>
                    index === 1 && <NavLink />
                  )
                })
              }
             ......
```

The concat fails:

```
to "/brokers/".concat(n.id)
```

And the conditional logic doesn't work .

How can I do it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changes (they will solve both the issues):

1- We can't return multiple elements, so use [React.Fragment](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html) (it will not add extra node to DOM).

2- Use [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) to put the variable inside the string.

Use this Code:

```
{props.tableData
  .map(n => {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <TableRow key={n.id}>
          <TableCell component="th" padding="checkbox">
            <Switch
              checked={n.commission === 1}
              onChange={(event) => props.setPayment(n.id, event.target.checked)}
              color="primary"
            />
          </TableCell>
          {
            Columns.map((c,index) => {

              const cell = <TableCell key={c.key} component="th" padding="checkbox">{c.format(n[c.key])}</TableCell>;

              if (index === 1) {
                return (
                  <NavLink key={c.key} className={classes.navLink} activeClassName={classes.activeNavLink}  to={`/brokers/${n.id}`} >
                    {cell}
                  </NavLink>
                )
              }
              return cell;
            })
          }
        </TableRow>
      </React.Fragment>
    )
  })
}
```

Comment: There's TableRow as the root element.

Comment: I didn't use the `Fragment` but I used the logic so I will accept this answer .

Answer (score 0):

You can use an expression

```
to={`/brokers/${n.id}`}
```

Comment: Thanks, and what about the first question ? How do I conditionally show the navigation only for the first column ?

Answer (score 0):

You should use like this:

```
to={`/brokers/${n.id}`}
```

Index starts from 0 not from 1. So, you need to set the condition to match the zero:

```
index === 0 &&
```

This will fix your issues:

```
{
 index === 0 && 
 <NavLink 
  className={classes.navLink} 
  activeClassName={classes.activeNavLink} 
  to={`/brokers/${n.id}`}>
}
    <TableCell 
      key={c.key} 
      component="th" 
      padding="checkbox">
        {c.format(n[c.key])}
    </TableCell>
{index===0 && </NavLink>}
 // not <NavLink />
```

Comment: Thanks . The index part still doesn't work , it shows an error as if I didn't close NavLink tag

Comment: I need the `TableCell` to be the link , shouldn't it be a child of `NavLink` ?

Comment: Thanks again , but wont this only render the table cell for the first index? I need every cell to be rendered , and only the first of each row to be a link component , so don't I need to conditionally close it too ?

Comment: I mean each index should have `TableCell` , only `index === 0` should also be wrapped inside a NavLink tag

Comment: Mmm, there's an error "expecting :" on `===` , I think it's expecting an object and not JSX

Comment: I don't think so, figure out, might be missing something.

Comment: did you copy my answer?

Answer (score 0):

React is not string gluing. You **can't do**

```
return (
  index === 1 && <NavLink  >
    <TableCell />
  index === 1 && <NavLink />
)
```

You **have to** operate on whole objects, it should be sth like this

```
return (
  {index === 1 ? <NavLink  >
      <TableCell />
    </NavLink>
    : <TableCell />
  }
)
```